How to solve this question using a range tree?
Question:
we’re given n treasures t1, ..., tn in the plane. Each treasure ti has an associated value vi. Your task is to design an
algorithm that returns the location of an axis-aligned k × k square
that maximizes the total value of the treasures contained in it.
Your algorithm should run in at most O(n^2\log^2n) time and space (i.e.,
independent of k and k is not a constant). As usual, also prove
correctness and analyze the running time and space. For simplicity,
you can assume that no two treasures have the same x- or y-coordinate.

How to solve this question using range tree? As far as I know, we can construct a two dimensional range tree based on the coordinates of the treasures. And then we need to do range queries and find the best outcome (the total value) within these queries. I know how to query on range tree, My confusion is where should we put our queries?

According to the question, we can put our query (top left corner) within [x_min, x_max-k]*[y_min, y_max-k], then the ways of putting out query would be quite large, I am confused.

What does "n2" mean in O(n2 log2 n)?

It means O(n^2*log^2n)

Note that, although I added an answer to your question, the range tree isn't really doing you any good.  You can get O(n^2) time just by sorting the points and iterating with a 2-pointer technique.

Given an optimal rectangle that contains the best collection of treasures, you could move it down, without reducing its value, until the top edge meets one of the treasures.
Similarly, you could move it to the right, without reducing its value, until the left edge meets one of the treasures.
Therefore, there is an optimal rectangle with both its left and top edges intersecting a treasure.  There are at most n2 such rectangles, one for each of the ways that you could pick the x coordinate from one treasure for the left edge, and the y coordinate from one treasure as the top edge.
Those are the rectangles you should test.

Assume k is really big, like half of n. Checking every kk square will take O(k^2) of time, so with this solution we have O(n^2k^2) time complexity.

@Dialecticus parent nodes need to be augmented with sums of their subtrees so that you can do each query in O(log^2 n) time.

Could you please describe your data structure, because I don't see it from the answer?
